# WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage gives different values in VBA vs C#

Tags: com, office-interop

I am translating a piece of code written in VBA to C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
What I observe that
`p.Range.Information[WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage]`
in C# gives a different value vs. when used in VBA
`p.Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)` where *p* is the Paragraph object.

This happens whenever a shape is present on the page of Word document. I was wondering why this is happening? Is there something different in rendering of documents when document is opened via C# vs VBA?

PS - in both cases, word visibility is set to false.

Edit: Update - I tried to set visibility to true and I do observe differences in document rendering when Document is launched using C# vs using VBA. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the problem. My code was trying to access header section like this

```
foreach (Section sect in objDoc.Sections)
        {
            foreach (HeaderFooter hf in sect.Headers)
            {
                someFunction(hf.Range.Paragraphs, false, false);
                if (hf.Shapes.Count > 0) // to handle shapes in Headers
                {
                    someFunction(hf.Shapes);
                }
            }
        }
```

For some reason, accessing headers changes the position of paragraphs in rendering causing the different values. To fix this, I now access headers as the last piece in my code. Hope this helps somebody.